# Yield return in parallel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, yield-return

I have a web app that allows the user to submit a job that can have many long running tasks. I am using yield return to allow the web app to show a progress bar however this enforces synchronous execution.

What i would like to do is take my list of tasks, run them in parallel but still provide feedback to the user.

In the below code, I still want to yield return after each call to Infer but i would like to run the loop in parallel. If this is not possible with yield then what are my options?

More specifically, what i want to do is split the requests into smaller collections and have those smaller collections run in parallel.

For the purposes of the question, lets say i wanted to split 'requests' into 'requests1' and 'requests2' and those then run in parallel yet still be able to yield back to the caller after each item completes.

```
    public IEnumerable<AnnotationRequest> Infer(List<Uri> fileUris, CancellationToken? token)
    {
        var requests = fileUris.Select(uri => new AnnotationRequest() { Uri = uri }).ToList();

        foreach ( var result in Infer(requests, token) )
        {
            yield return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question seems very broad. There are lots of different ways one might approach it. Have you tried a combination of starting separate tasks for each group and having each result added to a `BlockingCollection()`, which you enumerate via `GetConsumingEnumerable()` in the main method/thread above?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Peter Duniho comment above I implemented as per his suggestion and its working fine.

```
           var collection = new BlockingCollection<AnnotationRequest>();

           Task.Run(() =>
           {
               Parallel.ForEach(requests, (request) =>
              {
                  foreach (var result in Infer(request, token))
                  {
                      collection.Add(result);
                  }
              });

               collection.CompleteAdding();
           });

            foreach (var result in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                yield return result;
            }
```